# Не могу получить GET запрос (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, axios, fetch

Есть адрес для **GET** запроса:

> https://marketing.affboat.com/api/v2/users?api_token=3Y2lwzF4sWsJuxmnRoBZ4HCyaVo54divE816F9EwTi60s2QSJB9aHkVk896Y

Пытаюсь сделать запрос (и через **fetch** и через **axios**). Сначала получаю ошибку - "*... blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ..* ". Ошибку исправил, передав параметр: `{mode: 'no-cors'}`. Теперь статус ответа: **200**, запрос идет, но я не получаю ответ. Вот вообще не могу понять, в чем причина.

```
export const testQuery = async () => {
  const BASE_URL = 'https://marketing.affboat.com/api/v2/users?api_token=';
  const API_KEY =
    '3Y2lwzF4sWsJuxmnRoBZ4HCyaVo54divE816F9EwTi60s2QSJB9aHkVk896Y';

  const data = await fetch(BASE_URL + API_KEY, { mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));

  return data;
};
```

Очень надеюсь на ваши рекомендации и советы!

PS: запрос через Postman работает корректно. Даже если просто перейти по ссылке - вы сможете увидеть ответ. А вот, например, в консоль никак не могу передать. 
Пробовал через php - тоже корректно работает. Но мне нужно реализовать на JS.

Спасибо Вам!

Comment: Вы бы код показали для начала

Comment: UPD: код добавил

Answer (score 1):

Сервер должен отдавать заголовок:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

[Статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/114432/)